# Error: call to undeclared function 'EXTSM'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

Tags: c, linux, hp-ux, gnucobol, microfocus

We are migrating our application from HP-UX to LINUX and some of the c codes are using EXTSM function for sorting, but the application uses COBOL code with GNU COBOL. So, on compiling we are getting undeclared function error. How to replace this function in c code.

error: call to undeclared function 'EXTSM'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
EXTSM(func_cod, fcd);

We checked in the link provided below, maybe we need to use SORT instead.

https://bigdanzblog.wordpress.com/2020/11/09/cobol-sort-module-in-gnucobol/

Comment: Spot where the `EXTSM` function is implemented and forward declare it.

Comment: What *is* `EXTSM`? Is it a macro? Is it a function? Where is it *declared*? Like the error message says, functions in "modern" (if you count a 24 year old standard that since have been superseded *twice* as "modern") C needs to be declared before they are called. Take it as a chance to refactor the code to make it more modern and better and more robust.

Comment: Its a Callable Sort Module from Microfocus COBOL

Comment: Do you have a manual page for it showing what it returns and what parameters it expects (from a C point of view)?

Comment: I found this link: https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/object-cobol/ocu42/fhexsm.htm

Comment: You could compile the C code with the `-std=c89` flag, then this error won't occur.

Comment: @abhyudyagarg I found that page too but it's very hard to extract the C function prototype from that page.

Comment: its prototype is like this: EXTSM(char *,char *);

Comment: where first parameter is the function code and second is file control descriptor

Comment: @abhyudyagarg And, does it return `int`? If it doesn't, then the implicit function declaration you've used in the past made your program have undefined behavior

Comment: @Jabberwocky but will it still sort, it might fail at run time

Comment: @TedLyngmo no its return type is void

Comment: Ok, then your old program was "lucky" I guess. :-) Try adding this to your C code: `void EXTSM(char*, char*);` before using the function.

Comment: I didn't get this comment: "_but will it still sort, it might fail at run time_".

Comment: @Jabberwocky I meant that the error will not come after -std=C89 but will it perform as expected, is there a possibility it will fail as run time.

Comment: @TedLyngmo its a COBOL function this declaration will not work.

Comment: _"... is there a possibility it will fail as run time"_ - Yes, since the implicit declaration expects the function to return `int`.

Comment: @abhyudyagarg with `-std=C89` your code will compile and probably work as expected.

Comment: _"ts a COBOL function this declaration will not work"_  - Well: _"error: call to undeclared function 'EXTSM'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations"_ looks like a C error, not a Cobol error.

Comment: You should add the declaration in the **C** code, not the Cobol code.

Comment: Please show the actual code that you are trying to compile. Show a function where it calls `EXTSM`. Also show the `#include`s. `sub.h` seems like a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

`EXTSM` is an external COBOL `SORT` handler, which is available in some implementations as well as in external "products".

GnuCOBOL has no published release that provides that, if you use GnuCOBOL 3.1.2+ and are fine with patching this then you could include a [work-in-progress](https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/OCamlPro/gnucobol/pull/95.patch) that should already work in "most cases".
The best start would then be a [current GnuCOBOL 3.2 snapshot](https://ci.appveyor.com/api/projects/GitMensch/gnucobol-3-x/artifacts/gnucobol-3.2-dev.tar.gz?job=Image:%20Ubuntu2004) (considered stable).

Otherwise you  could replace the `CALL 'EXTSM'` by COBOL `SORT` statement, as you've recognized.